# Animate current location in Openlayers while the view follows

Tags: javascript, animation, openlayers

With openlayers I would like to make the current location visible and follow it with the view. The problem is that the current location updates from the device come in roughly every second and the resulting experience is not nice as the view jumps. This can be smoothed a little bit with a view animation, but then still the current location marker "jumps" on the map, like [in this example](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11776#issuecomment-735435955).

I created [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/current-position-i5581m) where I put the current location in an animation (I used [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html) as base) and update the view directly in the animation. (btw: how can I avoid adding the helperMarker?)
This works but calling `map.getView().setCenter` while the animation seems wrong and I think this is the reason that sometimes the animation is not smooth and it slows down and stutters (reproducible in Chrome and Firefox).

I then implemented another way where I move the current location marker outside of the map into a div element and overlay the map at a fixed location and then I only need to animate the view and center it to the location of this div element. This seems to work but feels like a hack as the current location marker is no longer part of openlayers with potential problems regarding synchronization.

So, what is the proper way with Openlayers for a smooth "synchronizated" of the view and a current location marker?

(So probably something like [this](https://samples.azuremaps.com/animations/animate-a-gps-trace) or [this](https://samples.azuremaps.com/animations/animate-along-a-route-path) but for openlayers)

Comment: The smooth animation examples already know the route.  To animate smoothly you would need to be stay one step behind since you do not know the duration and destination until the step finishes.

Comment: Yes, but this artificial delay is not the problem (yet), more the implementation of the synchronized animation itself. (In my case I could even try to guess the future as I have this "follow a route" use case. But this would be an improvement that I'll do later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a view animation that follows the path you can simply draw the marker in the view center in a `postrender` handler.

```js
vectorContext.drawGeometry(new Point(getCenter(map.getView().calculateExtent()))
```

I updated the example to keep the point in the view center during the animation (checkbox 'Smooth'):
https://codesandbox.io/s/track-position-vfdrx?file=/main.js

A postrender event on the vector layer only fires when at least one feature is drawn.
You can add the postrender event handler to the tile layer to avoid having a helper marker. (See my updated example above)

Comment: Thank you! This looks exactly what I was after. Will now try to get this working for my use case (https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-maps/pull/279)

Comment: Can you comment on the usage of the vectorLayer with the feature? Why do I need it if I call the postrender on the tileLayer? If I remove the vectorLayer, it still seems to work because the code in the postrender method draws the circle via vectorContext.drawGeometry (assuming smooth=true).

Comment: I adapted the code for my use case but somehow for heavier zooms the arrow reliably gets lost. Click "Navigation" here for this link: https://navi.graphhopper.org/?point=51.43921%2C14.245268&point=52.482989%2C13.368653&profile=car&layer=OpenStreetMap&fake (arrow is initially visible but gets lost) vs. this https://navi.graphhopper.org/?point=51.43921%2C14.245268&point=51.587523%2C13.934449&profile=car&layer=OpenStreetMap&fake (all is fine). Will investigate.

Comment: Ok, registering the postrender on the background layer fixes this. But not sure why the currentLocationLayer is initially and mostly working but on longer zoom durations disappears and then postrender won't be triggered.